# Estructuras de control anidadas para revisar un juego de dos matrices

Tags: php, estructuras

Estoy tratando de montar un script php para revisar dos conjuntos de matrices y definir las combinaciones posibles de ambas.

para que os hagais una idea, la primera matriz tiene los pares `2-0,3-0,4-0,5-0,6-0 y 7-0`, y la segunda matriz los pares: `1-2,1-3,1-4,1-5,1-6,1-7,2-6,3-6,4-6,5-6.`

Lo que estoy tratando de encontrar son las combinaciones que empiezen en 1 y acaben en 0 con todos los elementos de las dos matrices, osea:

```
 - 1-2,2-0
 - 1-3,3-0
 - 1-4,4-0
 - 1-5,5-0
 - 1-6,6-0
 - 1-7,7-0
 - 1-2,2-6,6-0
 - 1-3,3-6,6-0
 - 1-4,4-6,6-0
 - 1-5,5-6,6-0
```

Llevo una semana y no consigo armarlo en php.

Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias

Comment: Yo tengo una idea, pero creo que lo mejor sera que añadas algo del código de tus pruebas. Para aclarar un poco cuales son tus necesidades, que hay puntos que no he pillado del todo.

Comment: necesitamos tus avances para poder ayudarte...

Comment: es un poco rollo, ya que soy nuevo en esto.. habia creado un algoritmo que me parece que funciona, lo que me falla es el break... la idea es: 1) creo el array de los X-0,  y luego creo el array de los Y-X. 2) para cada elemento del array X-0 creo un subarray de los Y-Z que contenga los elementos de la formaq Y-X. 3) para cada elemento del subarray miro si el primer digito es 1. si es así, 1-Y-X-0 es una combinacion. 4) sino es 0, entonces tengo que iterar y buscar los elementos que tenga la forma Z-Y y crear otro subarray con los H-Z. es en esta iteración donde me pierdo y  Gracias

Comment: Bueno, ya lo consegui hacer, el secreto era montar un while y un foreach anidados y utilizar break 1 para ir saliendo en caso de coincidencias...